# XML Schema Explorer is not working

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2019

*I don't know if is correct to upload this question in this site but I'll take my chances.*

In Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.1.5 with .NET Version 4.8.03752. I'm trying to use the XML Schema Explorer to analyze an XSD file.

For some reason Visual Studio can not load the explorer correctly. The window is opened but the content (the tree) is not displayed. The image is frozen with the previous content.

[image: XML Schema Explorer with frozen image]

Visual Studio does not crash, I can close the explorer window without problem.

I tried to reopen the IDE, repair it and reinstall from scratch but nothing seems to work.

Any help how to fix this is appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I have exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed as per:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/657389/xml-schema-explorer-does-not-work.html

Just update your Visual Studio 2019 to the latest version.

*Update: I'm on VS Professional 2019 and the fix was in patch 16.3.4 - I was on 16.3.3 where I still experienced the issue).*

Comment: No, its still failing. I updated to Community 2019 Version 16.3.3 today and still is not working.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Still not working even today (16.4.3)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same behaviour, and I worked around it by temporarily disabling my JetBrains ReSharper extension in Extension Manager.

This is clearly a bug in Resharper or VS.

Comment: Disabling an add-on that many people have spent hundreds of dollars to purchase, isn't really a solution, sounds like you had a different problem caused by Resharper though.

Comment: @Ramhound I have changed my language from 'fix' to 'work around' and it will no doubt be of value to others with the same problem. The 'fix' can only presumably come from JetBrains or Microsoft.

Comment: @Ramhound and there is nothing to indicate the OP's issue is different to mine. The described behaviour was identical.

Comment: The only installed extensions are: Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics, Live Share, Cloud Explorer for VS 2019 Preview, Developer Analytics Tool, Visual Studio IntelliCode, Microsoft Library Manager, Dotnet Extensions for Test Explorer. Most of them I don't use them.